# Any web development packages similar to Serif WebPlus (discontinued - Win) or EverWeb (macOS) for Windows?

Tags: web-development, web, visual-design, desktop-publishing

A friend recently lost their computer that had an old version of Serif WebPlus on it that they've been using for over 10 years. They were very happy with WebPlus, but now they don't have a way to install it since it's been discontinued.

They need something that's very much a "drag-n-drop" and I suggested EverWeb for them, but they will not switch to macOS.

Are there any solid static creation drag and drop style web design / development packages that are on par with WebPlus or Everweb for Windows?